# The entry to the database from php does not work (SQL query did not give errors)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

there are two variables (login and password) that passes `ajax` to `php` by `POST` method. Next, I need to get everything from the database to find out if that name is already busy. I'm trying to do that, but nothing happens. Why? `SQLs` in `phpmyadmin` did not blunder the bugs.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'myDb');

if( $connection == false)
{
    echo 'Не удалось подключиться к базе данных!<br>';
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
session_start();
$name     = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$_SESSION['user'] = $name;
$_SESSION['pass'] = $password;

if (!isset($name, $password) || empty($name) || empty($password)){
    http_response_code(400);
    die();
}

$count = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE(`Name` == '$name'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($count) == 0)
{
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`Name`, `Password`) VALUES ('$name', '$password')");
}
mysqli_close($connection);
```

`AJAX`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var name = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/login_script.php',
      data: {
        user: name,
        pass: password
      },
      success: function() {
        document.location = 'chat.html';
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Invalid name or password');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.** Seriously, the first person who tries to use an apostrophe in their name or password will break your script.

Comment: Also, if things aren't working as predicted, try checking for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: One other thing: If this is a registration form, then you want to make sure that the username doesn't exist. Right now, you're checking for a username/password combination, which could register more than 1 user with the same username but different passwords. Checking for both user/pass is best when actually logging in.

Comment: If you need to check that the username is used already you need to make a query for username only (without password).

Comment: @TheCodesee yes, the insert simply does not put anything into the table

Comment: @МаксимБуяков Are there any rows in the table already? If there are, no queries will insert anything into it because of the line `if (mysqli_num_rows($count) == 0)`

Comment: @TheCodesee It does.

Comment: @МаксимБуяков Okay, that is good - it means your AJAX is executing fine. What about my previous question?

Comment: your code failed for a few reasons here, look at your SELECT query very carefully, then the other one; what doesn't happen for it?

Comment: @TheCodesee there are already some records in the table but I thought that I choose only names from the table and then compare them with the entered

Answer (score -1):

In your select statement, you where clause for $name has two equal signs.  Possible problem.

I would recommend reviewing what you are doing,  parts of it are in bad practice and not recommended.

Comment: Not my downvote here and you are correct to a certain extent. However, that doesn't cover the last query's failure.

Comment: My response was 3 minutes earlier than the original poster including the comment that the insert statement fails.  I can only respond based on what I know.

Comment: *"I can only respond based on what I know."*  - I see. Well, what you posted was probably downvoted based on the fact that the person may have thought that it was more fit to be a comment, and/or did not address the entire problem with what failed/not happening. I can't speak for the downvoter, but that's usually a reason for it, based on my past experience.